# Concrete 4th and 5th declension nouns

Tags: noun, teaching-method

I am having a hard time finding fourth and fifth declension nouns for teaching, because the common examples represent abstract concepts (like *spēs*). The common example *domus* is irregular. What are some regular fourth and fifth declension words for things you can point to (like animals or common articles of clothing), or things you can sit on or under (to practice oblative)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Manus* "hand" is of the fourth declension, though it is feminine.

*Specus* "cave" is normally masculine.

*Lacus* "lake".

*Fructus* can be a fruit, one that you pick from a tree.

There are some words of the neuter 4th declension (which has a different paradigm from that of the masculine words) which are concrete:

*Cornu* "horn".

*Genu* "knee".

There are probably many words of the fifth declension:

*Res* "thing" can be an object.

*Acies* can be a sharp edge or "point".

*Alluvies* a "pool of flooding water".

*Caesaries* "(head of) hair".

*Canities* can be used in a more concrete sense "gray hair".

*Congeries* "pile, heap".

*Facies* "face".

*Glacies* "ice".

Comment: *Senatus* and *exercitus* also seems like useful words for the Latin classroom; *anus*, while wholesome and innocuous, is perhaps not recommended; nor, while fun to demonstrate, *ructus*.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel We definitely learned about *anus* in high school Latin, in particular with regards to Queen Elizabeth II's *annus horribilis* and some tabloid rag's misspelling of it as *anus horribilis*.

Comment: @cmw now that's not nice! 

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel It was not, in fact, nice. But to a bunch of high school students, it was a hilarious faux pas on the tabloid's part. It also served as a cautionary tale about the difference a single letter could make.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel could be a good way to teach vowel length distinctions

Comment: @Tristan Especially because _anus_ and _ānus_ are different. It's a nice three-way minimal pair for vowel and consonant length.

Comment: To this list I would add _ariēs_ "ram", not least since it should be familiar from the zodiac.

Comment: @KefSchecter: That is of the third declension, isn't it? It might be instructional to also compare a list of words from the third declension on -es.

Comment: Whoops! I stand corrected!